# How to pass onChange and props in a function

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to change the id of my input using props but I am also using an onChange event.

```
import React from "react";

function Toggle({ onChange }) {
  return (
    <>
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" onChange={onChange} />
      <label htmlFor="switch"></label>
    </>
  );
}

export default Toggle;
```

I have tried like this:

```
import React from "react";

function Toggle({ onChange }, props) {
  return (
    <>
    <input type="checkbox" id={props.id} onChange={onChange} />
      <label htmlFor={props.id}>
      </label>
    </>
  );
}

export default Toggle;
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destructuring props, you can obtain the other values like this:

```
{ onChange, ...props }
```

Your attempt

```
({ onChange }, props)
```

Is destructuring the first argument, and assuming that there is a second one called props

The `...props` pattern from above is called a ["rest" pattern](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/), it also works with arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure `id` also.

```
function Toggle({ onChange, id }) {
  return (
    <>
    <input type="checkbox" id={id} onChange={onChange} />
      <label htmlFor={id}>
      </label>
    </>
  );
}
```